# Input-validation for free text fields

Tags: php, html, validation, security, htmlspecialchars

I searched a lot about form-validation in PHP. Unfortunately all tutorials about the validation mechanism are about specific fields like names, mails or dates. To check if the user-input in these fields are okay is simple with regex. But what is the best way to check free fields like a contact-us texteara or a comment field? Specifically in a comment field the user should also use "dangerous" chars like "<", ">" or " ' ".

What is the best way to handle the user input? Logically it's a bad idea to store the user data pure in a database. But it's also a bad idea to block characters like "<", ">" or " ' ".

I saw a function called `htmlspecialchars()` in PHP. A lot of websites say it's sufficient to call this function with the user input. In my eyes this solution is really risky without more checks.

Does anyone have any tips for me how I can securely validate my user input without reducing the "usability"? Thanks.

Comment: Well.. your question heavily depends on what are you going to do with this data. So what do you want to do with it and what data do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my case I want to store the data from the user in a database and print the database data on another page. The data from the user are written text - like a comment in a forum. If my user is a hacker, the text could contain badly things...

Comment: If you want to validate user input you might want to use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php), to get rid of leading and/or ending spaces. To be save against XSS [(which also is discussed in this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php), using `htmlspecialchars()` is a good idea.

Comment: And `htmlspecialchars()` is enough for this? So it's a good practise to allow all characters (my user could write code) an save it with `htmlspecialchars()` in the database? Really secure enough?

Comment: To be save against SQL injection
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php, might help you as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what is the best way to check free fields like a contact-us texteara or a comment field? Specifically in a comment field the user should also use "dangerous" chars like "<", ">" or " ' ".

You can use `if (strpos($string, '<') !== false)` for every dangerous character (where "dangerous" is very domain-specific).

> What is the best way to handle the user input? Logically it's a bad idea to store the user data pure in a database. But it's also a bad idea to block characters like "<", ">" or " ' ".

1. For preventing SQL injection, [just use prepared statements](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide). (Caveat: Not emulated prepared statements.)
2. For preventing XSS, [escape on output, never on input](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know).

There is no magical panacea for input validation. You have to know what your code is doing with the data to determine what's safe and what's unsafe. LDAP queries have different security requirements than SQL queries, XPath queries, or filesystem paths.

If you're looking for a more general input validation library for reasons outside security, [Ionizer](https://github.com/paragonie/ionizer) is worth checking out.